# Limit find results in SSH

Tags: ssh, command-line, putty

I using a line like this to search for a bunch of files:

```
find . -name "page.php
```

The results are hundreds of lines and I can't see it all.  (I'm trying to just copy/paste it into excel to analyze it).

I tried this:

```
find . -name "index1.php | less
```

That did something, but I was in this screen that I couldn't figure out how to exit out of.  I had to close putty and open it up again.

What is the best way to just limit the results to the viewable area so I can copy, then hit return and get the next group.

Or, is there a way to make putty not truncate the results?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: BTW `q` is the keyboard command to quit `less`

Comment: If you want a `less` alternative that requires you to just hit enter, that's `more`... but a larger scrollback buffer, or redirect to file, or learn how to use `less` sounds more like what you really want...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to get this into Excel? Why copy and paste?

`find . -name "index1.php" > out.txt`

Copy `out.txt` to your Excel machine ([SCP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/winscp/) is the easiest way), open it up.

Comment: Rename it `out.csv`, though, so that Excel will open it automagically.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is:

`find . -name "page.php" > some_file_name.txt`

This will redirect the output to some_file_name.txt which you can name what you please.

Answer (score 1):

In the PuTTY configuration, under the "Window" category there is a "Lines of Scrollback" option. Set this to a sufficiently huge number.